# Pytorch error: input is expected to be scalar type Long but found Float

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to create a deep learning algorithm to play snake. I'm trying to achieve this using PyTorch. Here is a snippet of my (messy, will fix that later) code:

```
## DOUBLE Q DEEP LEARNING NETWORK
class SnakeNet(nn.Module):
    """mini cnn structure
  input -> (conv2d + relu) x 3 -> flatten -> (dense + relu) x 2 -> output
  """
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()

        self.online = nn.Sequential(
            # nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_dim, out_channels=32, kernel_size=8, stride=4),
            # nn.ReLU(),
            # nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
            # nn.ReLU(),
            # nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1),
            # nn.ReLU(),
            # nn.Flatten(),
            # nn.Linear(3136, 512),
            # nn.ReLU(),
            # nn.Linear(512, output_dim),
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 200),
            nn.Linear(200, 20),
            nn.Linear(20, 50),
            nn.Linear(50, output_dim),
        )

        self.target = copy.deepcopy(self.online)

        # Q_target parameters are frozen.
        for p in self.target.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = False

    def forward(self, input, model):
        input = input.long()
        if model == "online":
            return self.online(input)
        elif model == "target":
            return self.target(input)
```

```
# EXPLOIT
        else:
            state = torch.tensor(state)
            state = state.unsqueeze(0)
            action_values = self.net(state, model="online")
            dir = torch.argmax(action_values, axis=1).item()
```

I get a error in line 221: `action_values = self.net(state, model="online")`

Stating that my input (state) is a Float, although its a tensorLong, which I proved by printing the type(). Before suggesting adding `state = state.type.tensorLong()` this didnt work, mainly because it was a long already.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snakeGame.py", line 324, in <module>
    prev_location, action = snake.act(current_state)
  File "snakeGame.py", line 222, in act
    action_values = self.net(state, model="online")
  File "/Users/gavinhartog/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "snakeGame.py", line 57, in forward
    return self.online(input)
  File "/Users/gavinhartog/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gavinhartog/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 141, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/Users/gavinhartog/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gavinhartog/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 103, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/Users/gavinhartog/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1848, in linear
    return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

And this is the original content and shape of state, before the torch.tensor:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], etc, etc, etc
```

I've tried different things like Conv2d and different loss functions, all the same error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a bit confusing. But I suppose you have type-cast the `state` to `float` and not to `long`

```
state = state.float()
```

Because `nn.Linear` always expects floating point numbers.

Comment: adding .float() produces the same error, thanks anyway

Comment: If adding `.float()` to state produces same error, then which one is still in long ? Point is, you need everything in float. Check if any other tensor is in long.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try again with this:

```python
stats=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(type(stats))
stats=torch.tensor(stats).type(torch.LongTensor)
state = stats.unsqueeze(0)
print(type(stats))
```